# MongoDb ObjectId or native id

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB, you can use an ObjectID or you can use your own id. I understand, that there are several advantages in using ObjectID's instead of custom string ids, but is it in all cases better to use ObjectID?

In my project, I have around 3 million documents which represent books. Every book has an unique EAN code (13 chars). So since I have to store and index this field in any case, I don't see the advantage of useing an ObjectID, because this means one extra (useless) field and one extra index.

But perhaps I have overlooked something?

Comment: No, I dont wanna disable the _id, I just asked, if I its (in my situation) a good idea, to use the ean-string as _id instead of ObjectId (not instead of _id)

Comment: So because of the ObjectID is a [12 byte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) long data. I guess you will save up 3 000 000 * 12 byte. But makes request slower (because it will works with item that are 1 byte bigger).

Comment: I did the same in one of my projects no issues so far.